# Magento: increment_id empty after first order

Tags: magento, increment

I need the increment id from an order to create a folder on my server for moving some order specific files there, after a customer has successfully ordered something. This is what I've got so far:

```
$chkoutSess = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$lastOrderId = $chkoutSess->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$incid = $order->getData("increment_id");
```

I guess this can be done much easier but it works for me. The problem I have with this is that the `$order` is totally empty when I order something "the first time". After this it always works. So I think I can only get this data out of a session object when there's an actual session...this of course is senseless because there should always be a "lastOrderId" when a customer orders something. Is there any other way to simply get the last order and it's incremented out of the database? I tried several things but the objects where always empty..

The function I use is executed right after the user successfully hits the order submit button (event observer "sales_order_place_after"). Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: But whole order object is passed to `sales_order_place_after` observer, you can use it there (`$event->getOrder()`). Why you are trying to get order id from session?

Comment: Your solution did work for me so far...think that´s what i missed here...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `$chkoutSess->getRealOrderId();` and not `$chkoutSess->getLastOrderId();`